# Python unable to understand directory structure after moving the project to a cloud

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, vps

Recently I bought a droplet in digital ocean to put my project live.It works just fine in my local computer and doesn't have any problem with the directory structure.However once I put this on a server, Python throws an error.Below is my project structure in my local computer.

[image]

Now when I move it to a server, this is my project structure

[image]

Now If I run a test file just to test the imports

```
cd integretation
ls

__init__.py  __pycache__  request_constructor.py  test.py
```

**test.py**

```
from format_data.output_filter import output_filter


print("Yes")
```

Now I run the file

```
python3 test.py
```

I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from format_data.output_filter import output_filter
ImportError: No module named 'format_data'
```

Why is that happening though the same import structure works in my local computer? I even tried to change the import to something like this

```
from service_rest.format_data.output_filter import output_filter
```

But this doesn't help either.What is going wrong?

Note: I have removed the topmost level directory **ServiceHandler** when transferring the files to the server.But adding it back doesn't help either.

Comment: down vote
When you print(url_for('index')) (assuming you are using some sort of web framework like flask), what is the directory it shown? And what is your server's root directory setting

Comment: @well I can't use your command because before it runs, I get all sorts of import errors.I am using flask by the way.

Comment: Did you Install all the Python packages on Digital Ocean?